# Required Field validator Not working from OnCheckedChanged Event in Code Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind, requiredfieldvalidator

I am doing something logically very simple but It aint working.

I have a Required field validator in a textbox.On selection of a radiobutton, it becomes mandatory to have something on the textbox.

1) I have tried adding a required field validator which is disabled and then Onchecked changed event of the radiobutton, enable the required field validator.But this doesnt work
2) I have kept the required field validator enabled and the text of the textbox as #.Oncheckedchanged event of the radiobutton I clear the text of the textbox and still the rValidator doesnt work.
Have tried String.empty and passing values both.

I need this on the server side only.Broke my head for many hours cant find a way out.Copy pasting the code below.
Any help will be appreciated.

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbNAVEst"  GroupName="NAVEstimate2" runat="server" />
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbMonNAVEst" Text="Insert [0-100]" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> &nbsp
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNavEst2" Width="100px" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem> Hours </asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem> Business Days</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem> Calendar Days</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList> <asp:RangeValidator
                                        ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" Type="Integer" ErrorMessage="Enter Values Between 0 to 100 Only" ControlToValidate="tbMonNAVEst" MaximumValue="100" MinimumValue="0"></asp:RangeValidator>
                        <br />

                          <asp:Label ID="lblBlankNAVEst2" runat="server" Width="60px"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="rbOtherNAVEst" AutoPostBack="true"  OnCheckedChanged="ClearNAVEstimate"  GroupName="NAVEstimate2" runat="server" />
                            <asp:Label ID="lblOtherNAV" runat="server" Text="Other"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbOtherNAV" Text="#" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator  ID="rfvNAVEStimate" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="tbOtherNAV" Enabled="true" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Values" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                              <br />
```

Code Behind is:

```
protected void ClearNAVEstimate(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         tbOtherNAV.Text = String.Empty;
        // rfvNAVEStimate.Enabled = true; ( tried this when I had Validators enabled as false.This also did not work)
         tbOtherNAV.Focus();          
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

The checked change of your radiobutton fires a postback, but the required field validator will do a validation in the client side , which is blocking you. So you should disable the required filed validator in the client side. Write a client side onCheckedChange event for that radio button , and then in that event, Enable or disable the requiredfield validator in the client side using javascript.
you can use the below javascript functionality

```
ValidatorEnable(getElelementById('#<%=rfvNAVEStimate.ClientID %>') ,fale); // this will disable the validator
```

if you pass `true` . it will enable the validator

Comment: Correct me if m wrong, but I dont think we can write a client side event for an asp radio button. And there are few other things that happen on click as well in my code behind. Is there no other way to do this on server side..

Comment: You can bind a client side event for the radio button using jQuery.
So your client side evnt will fire first and then it will go for the server side event.

Comment: so is there no way to do it server side?

Comment: If your required field validator is there, it will prevent any postback. Then I think, better you remove that required field validator, and just do the validation in code. Or One more thing, you can do is, instead of the required field validator, use asp.net custom validator. So for that custom validator you can write a client side or server side function, and in that function check if the radio button is checked or not and do the validation based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Guys...
If I use rfvNAVEstimate.ISvalidate() function , It gets fired..
Problem Solved... Still Posting it here for Others.